# Use Google's location service?

Tags: gps, location-services

When I turn on my device's GPS, Android issues the following:

> Use Google's location service?
>   Let Google help apps determine location.  This means sending anonymous location data to Google, even when no apps are running.   [  ] Don't show again

That seems like a bad idea.  So I click 'Disagree' each time.  If I select the 'Don't show again' checkbox and then click Disagree, will Android interpret that as a permanent Agree or Disagree?

My experience is that sometimes what you think will happen with these sorts of options is not what really happens.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you if it's a good idea or not, that really depends on the type of user you are, but what I can tell is the following:

That feature's main goal is to improve some of Google's services, which means, you may get location based ads, and if you have Google Now, location based cards, among others. Besides, many apps use Google to retrieve your location in a more efficient way.

Now, if you are still concerned about your privacy, do not worry. You can always enable/disable it later. How? Well, it depends on your device's configuration, but I think it's pretty safe to say you'll find the option by opening the app "Google Settings" and then in "Location".